# How to associate a downloaded certificate with tomcat

Tags: ssl

I have a  downloaded a free ssl certificae and  how can i make it to configure under Apache Tomcat ??

I have issued this below command  to import the downloaded file

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file Thawte.crt -keystore keystore.jks

But how this will be associated with the tomcat server ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your Connector description in the `server.xml` file to something like

```
<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
-->
```

See the [SSL documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you , That link confused me a lot . is this the procedure same if we create a .csr file ?? using the keytool option ??

Comment: They additionally describe how to do a CSR and after that import the CA's response correctly. You can probably skip that. In order to operate your SSL certificate you need a key store file that contains the private key and the SSL certificate that you downloaded. Additionally it might be a good idea to also include any intermediates and the root CA certificate so that your server will always send the complete certificate chain instead of only the server certificate.